# Reset State Variables To Initial Values xcode

Tags: variables, button, swiftui, state, reset

What is the best way to go about resetting state variables, using a button. I've tried a load of different funcs but none work.

I'm trying to use this button:

```
primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {

Code

},secondaryButton: 
.cancel()
```

To reset these State variables:

```
@State var statsValue1 = 0 
@State var statsValue2 = 0 
@State var statsValue3 = 0 
@State var statsValue4 = 0 
@State var statsValue5 = 0 
@State var statsValue6 = 0
```

(which are in the main content view)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a view model, the `@Published` property wrapper notifies about any changes of the model and the `reset` function creates a new instance

```
struct Model {
    var value1 = 0
    var value2 = 0
    var value3 = 0
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = Model()
    
    func reset() {
        model = Model()
    }
}
```

and a simple test logic in the content view

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Value 1: \(viewModel.model.value1)")
            Text("Value 2: \(viewModel.model.value2)")
            Text("Value 3: \(viewModel.model.value3)")
            Divider()
            Button ( "Delete", role: .destructive, action: viewModel.reset )
            Button { viewModel.model.value1 += 1 } label: { Text("Increment value 1") }
            Button { viewModel.model.value2 += 1 } label: { Text("Increment value 2") }
            Button { viewModel.model.value3 += 1 } label: { Text("Increment value 3") }
        }
    }
}
```